# System.MethodAccessException Whenever Using Matrix3DHelper.Multiply

Tags: .net, uwp

Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Media3D.Matrix3DHelper.Multiply throws System.MethodAccessException at runtime when I call it.

```
Matrix3D matrix1 = new Matrix3D();
matrix1.M11 = 0.7;
Matrix3D matrix2 = new Matrix3D();
matrix2.M23 = 0.2;

var combined = Matrix3DHelper.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2); // throws error here
```

This is an included class and the method is public. The method is [not in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.matrixhelper) though!?!

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Clean repro project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BueEzQo6CgGlflv03mrVoVJIcw_TMH9x/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Matrix3DHelper.Multiply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.media3d.matrix3dhelper.multiply) is documented - your link was to MatrixHelper not Matrix3DHelper.

The documentation says not to use it from .Net:

> C# and Microsoft Visual Basic code should use the multiplication operator instead.

```
// Instead of this:
//   var combined = Matrix3DHelper.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);
// do this:
var combined = matrix1 * matrix2;
```

Comment: Thanks.  FYI I was using it because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.matrix3dprojection)